# C++ boost variant question

Tags: c++, boost, variant, compile-time, boost-mpl

I know that `boost::variant` uses `boost::mpl` stuff behind it and has a mpl-compatible typedef `types`.

Let's say I have a simple typedef: `typedef boost::variant<bool, int> Variant;`

Now I have another template function, let's say:

```
template <typename T> T function() {
   // ...
}
```

I want this function to act differently for two cases: when `T` a part of `Variant::types` and when it's not.

Obviously, I have to do something like

```
template <typename T>
typename boost::enable_if<CONDITION, T>::type function() {
   // Implementation for the case T is in Variant::types
}

template <typename T>
typename boost::disable_if<CONDITION, T>::type function() {
   // Implementation for the case T is ***NOT*** in Variant::types
}
```

The only thing I don't know is this `CONDITION`.

*Now - I do think it's possible to make a compile-time query if `T` is a part of `Variant::types`.*

***Does someone know how?***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is indeed possible, `Variant::types` meets the requirement of a Mpl.Sequence type and therefore can be queried like any sequence.

Therefore, using `boost::mpl::contains` from [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/contains.html):

```
// using C++0x syntax to demonstrate what CONDITION should be replaced with
template <typename T>
using Condition = boost::mpl::contains<Variant::types,T>
```

Nothing simpler, when you know about it ;)

The full MPL Manual is available in [HTML](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual.html) format, should you need some more algorithms.

Comment: +1. Since the question is tagged C++ and not C++0x, you might want to add a comment about your `using` syntax. Also, didn't you mean to write `Variant::types` instead of `Variant` in `boost::mpl::contains` ?